# ethers.rs - PendingTransaction returns Ok(None)

Tags: pending-transactions, ethers.rs

I'm running into some issue while testing a smart contract.
So I published a smart contract, made a call using cli, and I got the data of the call:

```
    let data = "0x6c814389000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004307830310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043078303200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000430783033000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000430783034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004307830350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043078303600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
```

And the transaction succeed.
Now, I'm trying to make a transaction request using a signer middleware:

```
            let provider = Provider::<Http>::connect(&config.provider).await;
            let chain_id = provider.get_chainid().await.unwrap().as_u64();
            let wallet =
                LocalWallet::from_str(&private_key).expect("Bad private key passed to sign_legacy");
            let wallet = wallet.with_chain_id(chain_id);
            let middleware = SignerMiddleware::new(provider, wallet.clone());

        ...


        let data: Vec<u8> = data.into(); // data was the raw string. I also tried to use hex::parse() but same result

        let tx = TransactionRequest {
            to: Some(ethers::types::NameOrAddress::Address(
                module.bridge_address.parse().unwrap(),
            )),
            data: Some(data.into()),
            from: Some(pubkey),
            value: Some(0u32.into()),
            gas_price: Some(1000000000u32.into()),
            gas: Some(455000u32.into()),
            nonce: Some(U256::from(55648436)),
            chain_id: Some(U64::from(module.chain_id)),
        };
        let tx = middleware.send_transaction(tx.clone(), None).await;
        debug!("result: {:?}", tx);
        let tx = tx.unwrap().log_msg("Pending transfer hash").await;
        debug!("result: {:?}", tx);
        tx.unwrap().unwrap();
```

When I get there, the transaction is sent, I get a pending transaction:

```
[2023-11-16T19:18:08Z DEBUG external_signer] result: Ok(PendingTransaction { tx_hash: 0xf8a38a1d995dbb90a7eac7e6f682a79546818785a8bc725204e870a2cb5173c1, confirmations: 1, state: PendingTxState { state: "InitialDelay" } })
```

But then, I receive Ok(None), and the transaction is not executed. Why do I receive this ? As it's just None and not an error, I cannot get the reason why I'm getting this.
I don't have any failed request on Infura (the provider I'm using), and when searching the tx_hash on the explorer, I get nothing.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like the issue was coming from the Nonce.
Yesterday, when Nonce was set to "None", Transaction wouldn't pass as middleware was throwing a "already known" error, and when choosing a random nonce, I was at least getting the PendingTransaction.
Today, when showing a colleague my issue, I put the Nonce back to "None" to show him the issue, and it worked.
I think I will keep the post up as "archive", but I really have no idea what changed between these two days.

Edit: found the issue.
Basically, when nonce is set to "None", it will automatically select the next nonce available (let's say, x), and you send a transaction that is badly formatted, it will take some time to be reverted, and during all this time, selecting nonce None will select x again, that is already known. So in this issue, time was the solution